# get json string from ajax response text

Tags: ajax, extjs

The response text of my Ajax request is this :

```
"<json>
<![CDATA[
{"status":true,"filterMap":{ "summary":"Summary","total":"Total","myProfileMsg":"Opening my profile,   please wait","cgBase":"CG Base","export1":"Export"}}
]]>
<offsetinTime>19800000</offsetinTime></json>"
```

I want to extract just the json string  from this.. ie. what i want is :

```
{"status":true,"filterMap":{ "summary":"Summary","total":"Total","myProfileMsg":"Opening my profile,   please wait","cgBase":"CG Base","export1":"Export"}}
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace()` & `split()` functions of **String** to achieve it:

```js
var json ='<json><![CDATA[{"status":true,"filterMap":{"summary":"Summary","total":"Total","myProfileMsg":"Opening my profile,   please wait","cgBase":"CG Base","export1":"Export"}}]]><offsetinTime>19800000</offsetinTime></json>';
var extractedJson=json.replace('<json><![CDATA[','').split(']')[0];
document.body.innerHTML=extractedJson;
```